# How to overwrite next cell with Excel QueryTables URL reply

Tags: excel, vba

I need an http request to a website that does a simple lookup, taking a UK grid reference (of the form "SD676256"). The website returns a descriptive string (eg. "VC59 South Lancashire") or an empty string "" on error.

The following code inserts the returned text to the neighbouring cell and advances one cell. However, if the target cell is not empty, it inserts a new column.

- How do I make it overwrite the existing cell instead?
- How do I get the result string returned into a variable instead of it being inserted directly into the sheet (so that I can chop out the numerical part, 59 in VC59...)?
- How can the code be improved (I'm a total neophyte with Excel/VBA)

Code:

```
Sub Lookup()

    gridref = ActiveCell.Value
    url = "http://lookupwebsite.co.uk/?r=" & UCase(gridref)

    Set result = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & url, _
                                             Destination:=ActiveCell.Next)
    
    With result
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

**Edited** to disable background queries.

Comment: "if the target cell is not empty, it inserts a new column" - clear the cell before you add the query.

Comment: Can you provide the website url? Using querytables in this way is an expensive process as is using offset with select. Personally, I would have all gridrefs in Col A and read those results in an array then redim preserve to dimension for second column of results e.g. arr = [A2:A3].Value: ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To 2). Then loop the first dimension of the array, issuing xmlhttp requests using the value at the current iteration and store the result of interest in the array. When loop complete, write results to sheet. If you want to remove results where "" in col B

Comment: then apply autofilter and remove those rows. I will type up an example for you tomorrow if I have time. Use a regex helper function to remove the numeric parts with regex replace during loop before storing in array.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr  - I could cache lookups to speed it up (can vba create a hashtable that persists between macro calls?), but there are too many grid refs to list them all. Each grid square (SD above) has entries from SD000000 to SD999999. There are 70 (ish) squares for the UK. They are defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams - that seems obvious now you've mentioned it :-)  However, clearing the target cell works only if the cell *below* the target cell is empty and I can't clear that one in advance. If that cell is not empty, the same column insertion occurs.

Comment: `Application.CountA(ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Resize(2,1))` will be zero if the cell to the right and the one below that are both empty.  QHarr's suggested approach would be more manageable: (eg) a simple GET using xmlhttp would allow you to work without needing to place content on the sheet first.   https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/

Comment: I would need to discuss your caching query in more detail as I am not clear how you intend to use that. You can usually ping me with @qharr in the [dawghaus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus-). I'm not around super often but try to check in from time to time.